# How to get the field value from a specific tab using C#

Tags: c#, webforms

Let's say I have a server page named `TestInfo.aspx`. There's a field on it called `testLocation`.

It also has three tabs (`Attempt1`, `Attempt2`, `Attempt3`) in it that use the same server control, `TestAttempt.ascx` with two fields on it (`test Date`, `testScore`).

I am already able to tell which tab is the latest one being used (ex. the user failed `Attempt1`, and is now on `Attempt2`, so `Attempt2` is the current tab).

In the code behind in `TestInfo.aspx.cs`, how do I get a handle on the current tab (i.e. `Attempt2` in this example), so I can get the `testDate` and `testScore` field values off just that specific tab (i.e. `Attempt2`)?

Thanks.

I am very new to C# so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll take a go at this.

First up? You don't say what kind of tab control you are using. (There is not a native one to asp.net webforms).

So, I'll have to take a wild guess, and say use the jQuery one.

So, I have 3 tabs, and behind each tab is a user control.

The user control lets me select a hotel, and a start and end date.

So, most easy here is to "expose" the controls as a public get (and set if desired) in that user control.

So, here is the user control:

```
<div style="float:left">

    <h3>Select Hotel</h3>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotel" runat="server" 
        Width="200px"
        DataValueField="ID"
        DataTextField="HotelName" 
        AutoPostBack="true" >
    </asp:DropDownList>

</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:30px">
    <h3>Select Start Date</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date">
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:30px">
    <h3>Select Start Date</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date">
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

So, a simple drop down, and 2 date textbox controls.

Code behind for the user control is this:

```
public partial class USelectHotel : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            cboHotel.DataSource =
                General.MyRst("SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblhotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
            cboHotel.DataBind();
            cboHotel.Items.Insert(0, "Select Hotel");
        }
    }

    public int HotelID
    {
        get {return Convert.ToInt32(cboHotel.SelectedItem.Value);}
        set { HotelID = value; }
    }

    public string HotelName
    {
        get {return cboHotel.SelectedItem.Text;} 
        set {cboHotel.Text = value;}                
    }

    public DateTime dtStart
    {
        get { return Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text); }
        set { txtStartDate.Text = value.ToString(); }
    }

    public DateTime dtEnd
    {
        get { return Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text); }
        set { txtEndDate.Text = value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

So, note how we "exposed" the controls as public properties of that user control.

So, now our web page, 3 tabs, and each tab with the user control is this:

```
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Hotel Choice</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Hotel Choice</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third Hotel Choice</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <h3>Choose First Destination Hotel</h3>
                <uc1:USelectHotel runat="server" id="USelectHotel" />
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <h3>Choose Second Destination Hotel</h3>
                <uc1:USelectHotel runat="server" ID="USelectHotel1" />
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                <h3>Choose Third Destination Hotel</h3>
                <uc1:USelectHotel runat="server" ID="USelectHotel2" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdContinue" runat="server" Text="Continue" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="cmdContinue_Click" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HtabSel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="0" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>


        <script>

            $(function () {

                $("#tabs").tabs(
                    {
                        active : $('#HtabSel').val(),
                        activate: function (event, ui) {
                            var activeTab = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active");
                            $('#HtabSel').val(activeTab)
                        }
                    }
                );
            });


        </script>
```

And to make the code behind simple, then I wired up an event on the jQuery.UI tab control to set the hidden field to the current tab index. This makes the code behind rather simple then, and is this:

```
    protected void cmdContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sHotelName = "";
        DateTime dtStart;
        DateTime dtEnd;

        USelectHotel cHotel = USelectHotel;
        switch (Convert.ToInt32(HtabSel.Value))
        {
            case 0: cHotel = USelectHotel; break;
            case 1: cHotel = USelectHotel1; break;
            case 2: cHotel = USelectHotel2; break;
        }

        sHotelName = cHotel.HotelName;
        dtStart = cHotel.dtStart;
        dtEnd = cHotel.dtEnd;

        Debug.Print($"Tab = {HtabSel.Value} Hotel name= {sHotelName} Start Date = {dtStart.ToString()}");

    }
```

So, the result is now this:

[image]

So, you "might" be able to try and parse the page, or use page.FindControl(), but as above shows, by exposing the desired controls as public get/setters from the user control, then code behind on the given web page can with ease get such values from a given user control.